# Execute code in the beginning of a new week

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am in need of your expertise to solve a code problem I currently do not know which is the best way to program it. The problem is:
Only in the beginning of a new week, I want to some clickable divs display on my webpage. When you click one of those divs, they will be added to a database and the divs will be hidden. And in the beginning of the next week, they will automatically appear again.

How do I program this the best way using Javascript/PHP/SQL?

My spontaneous idea is to create a database table where I store all the values of the weeks, and then when a new week starts, the code compares the values in the table and the value of the current week. Is this a good idea?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Setup a cron job which will execute in the beginning of the week and call your php function, which will show the divs

Answer (score 0):

Simple Using Php :
If your week start day is Sunday then you can use **Sun** as compare validator or if it starts with Monday then you can use **Mon** as parameter.

```
  <?php
    if(date("D")=="Sun")
    {
      echo "<DIV>Show Data</DIV>";
      echo "<DIV>Data</DIV>";
    }
    {
     echo "<DIV> Do Not Show Data</DIV>";  
      echo "<DIV style='display:none;'>Data</DIV>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what about hiding

Comment: @rahul Ah, this makes total sense to me. It is a lot easier to code than I expected! But what if the page is reloaded on the start of the week, will the DIVs pop back up?

Comment: Yes definately, they will if it is sunday then it will show all the time in entire day, no matter how much time you refresh it.

Answer (score 0):

You said "they will be added to a database", so check record exist before loading the divs.

```
<?php
    if(date("D")=="Sun") {
       if (!dataFound) { // if not record found
          echo "<DIV>Show Data</DIV>";
          echo "<DIV>Data</DIV>";
       }
    } else {
       echo "<DIV> Do Not Show Data</DIV>";  
       echo "<DIV style='display:none;'>Data</DIV>";
    }
 ?>
```